# Generic criteriaUpdate set boolean = !boolean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I want to use criteriaUpdate to create an update query like this:

```
UPDATE <SOME TABLE>
SET SELECTED = !SELECTED
WHERE
[DYNAMIC QUERY HERE]
```

The closest I could get was with the code:

```
public <T> Query createRevertSelectionQuery(Class<T> clazz, EntityManager em, Specification<T> s) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaUpdate<T> criteriaUpdate = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(clazz);
    Root<T> root = criteriaUpdate.from(clazz);
    Predicate p = cb.and(new Predicate[] {s.toPredicate(root, null, cb)});
    Expression<Boolean> e =cb.not((root.get("selected").as(Boolean.class)));
    Path<Boolean> selected = root.get("selected");
    criteriaUpdate.set(selected, e);
    criteriaUpdate.where(p);
    Query q = em.createQuery(criteriaUpdate);       
    return q;       
}
```

but it fails because I get the following query:

```
update com.redknee.suspense.mgt.model.Moc as generatedAlias0 
set generatedAlias0.selected = generatedAlias0.selected <> true 
where 
[dynamic query]
```

giving me the error

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: <> near line 1, column 118

Anyone can help please?

Comment: Seems like spring, spring-boot? Add relevant tag to question if is. How about the specification?

Comment: Thank you @pirho.
The specification is the following:
I want to update a generic entity T with the where clause specified in "Specification s" set the column "selected" = "NOT(selected)"

If I could make 
"set generatedAlias0.selected = (generatedAlias0.selected <> true) " maybe it would work, but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: No prob. And the Specification seems to be only for appending if there are other predicates.

Comment: Wrong dialect maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a bug or if it is just not meant to be used this way .

In where-clause NOT and any other operands  work like a charm. But, no matter what you try Hibernate query builder seems always to optimize those parenthesis away  (*in my opinion it might still be a good habit to always use parenthesis but its only an opinion*).

One way to force parenthesis is to use JPA `Subquery`. See below example. Note that i have slightly altered the JPA object names by my own taste and not included the `Specification` because it is not relevant to this solution:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<T> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(clazz);
Root<T> from = update.from(clazz);
Path<Boolean> selected = from.get("selected");

// Subquery just "joins back" to the same row and
// returns a negated boolean value of "selected" from the original row
Subquery<Boolean> subSelect = update.subquery(Boolean.class);
Root<T> subFrom = subSelect.from(clazz);
subSelect.select(cb.not(selected));
subSelect.where(cb.equal(from.get("id"), subFrom.get("id")));

update.set(selected, subSelect);
```